# MS Clear Screen Saver doesn't work

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

I have a problem with really exotic thing - Microsoft Clear Screen Saver.
As it's name suggests, it's a screen saver, that's transparent (MS posted it as a part of W2k Resource Kit). When you move the mouse/hit a key, the "lock" dialog appears.
I would like to use this to view servers desktops without need to log in.

I tested it on my XP's, and it works flawlessy.
But on W2K3 servers it doesn't work. After the screensaver timeout, the error message is displayed:

"The Clear Screen Saver cannot display the user desktop after the workstation has been locked"

Answer (score 1):

That would be security built into Server 2003. I don't know if you can get around it or not; but keep in mind that anyone could walk up to the server and see what's on the screen. That sounds like a really terrible idea.

Comment: Well, if someone passed our datacenter's physical security, then peeking server's desktop will be last of our problems :) I would like to know more about the "security" built into Server 2003 - any specifics?

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking for the same thing - obviously 2008 now.   I have found a third party product that fits the bill.  Have a look at [Transparent Screen Lock PRO](http://www.e-motional.com/TScreenLock.htm).  Not only does it do what you requested it optionally allows multiple users unlock the screen using their own username and password.

Comment: Product advertisements are frowned upon on this site, -especially- if you don't give out fill disclosure. Are you in any way affiliated with the product you linked to?